# Exceção quando vai gerar boleto bancário com a Boleto.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, exceção, boleto

Tenho um sistema que gera boletos do Santander usando uma DLL específica que foi baixada da internet. O nome é "Boleto.net". Preciso criar um boleto Bradesco. Alterei onde passava os dados do banco Santander para os dados do Bradesco, mas na hora de gerar o boleto da um erro dizendo que não foi passado o valor para um objeto específico. Qual o `TipoArquivo` do Bradesco para passar a validação no boleto?

```
        public BoletoBancario GerarBoletoBradesco(BoletoModel bol)
        {
            BoletoBancario boletoBancario = new BoletoBancario();

            boletoBancario.CodigoBanco = 237;

            ContaBancaria cb = new ContaBancaria();

            cb.Agencia = bol.cedente.Agencia;
            if (bol.cedente.DigAgencia != "")
                cb.DigitoAgencia = bol.cedente.DigAgencia;

            cb.Conta = bol.cedente.Conta;
            if (bol.cedente.DigConta != "")
            cb.DigitoConta = bol.cedente.DigConta;

            Cedente c = new Cedente();
            c.CPFCNPJ = bol.cedente.CNPJ;
            c.Nome = bol.cedente.Nome;
            c.Carteira = bol.Carteira;
            c.ContaBancaria = cb;
            c.Codigo = bol.cedente.Codigo;
            if (bol.cedente.DigCedente != "")
                c.DigitoCedente = int.Parse(bol.cedente.DigCedente);    
            //Até o momento o Convênio é o mesmo número do código do cedente
            c.Convenio = int.Parse(c.Codigo);

            BoletoNet.Boleto b = new BoletoNet.Boleto(bol.DataVencimento, bol.ValorBoleto, bol.Carteira, 
                bol.NossoNumero, c);

            b.NumeroDocumento = bol.NumeroDocumento;
            b.DataProcessamento = DateTime.Now.Date;
            b.DataDocumento = bol.DataDocumento;
            b.JurosMora = bol.ValorMulta;

            BoletoNet.Endereco end = new BoletoNet.Endereco();
            end.Bairro = "";
            end.End = bol.sacado.Endereco;
            end.CEP = bol.sacado.CEP;
            end.Cidade = bol.sacado.Cidade;
            end.Complemento = "";
            end.Email = "";
            end.Logradouro = "";
            end.Numero = "";
            end.UF = bol.sacado.UF;

            BoletoNet.Sacado s = new BoletoNet.Sacado(bol.sacado.CNPJCPF, bol.sacado.Nome, end);
            b.Sacado = s;

            //Aqui passa o codigo do banco bradesco
            //b.EspecieDocumento = new EspecieDocumento_Santander("17");
            b.EspecieDocumento = new EspecieDocumento_Bradesco("13");

            Instrucao objInst1 = new Instrucao(237);
            objInst1.Descricao = bol.infAdicional.Instrucao1;
            Instrucao objInst2 = new Instrucao(237);
            objInst2.Descricao = bol.infAdicional.Instrucao2;
            Instrucao objInst3 = new Instrucao(237);
            objInst3.Descricao = bol.infAdicional.Instrucao3;
            Instrucao objInst4 = new Instrucao(237);
            objInst4.Descricao = bol.infAdicional.Instrucao4;

            b.Instrucoes.Add(objInst1);
            b.Instrucoes.Add(objInst2);
            b.Instrucoes.Add(objInst3);
            b.Instrucoes.Add(objInst4);

            //Importante para o calculo do digito verificador
            //b.PercentualIOS = 0;

            boletoBancario.Boleto = b;
            boletoBancario.MostrarCodigoCarteira = true;
            boletoBancario.Boleto.Valida();

            return boletoBancario;
        }

public ActionResult GeraRemessa()
        {
            BoletoNet.Boletos lb = new BoletoNet.Boletos();
            BoletoNet.Cedente cd = new BoletoNet.Cedente();
            foreach (var item in listaBoletos)
            {
                Boleto bol = new Boleto();
                BoletoNet.BoletoBancario bolBanc = new BoletoNet.BoletoBancario();
                //bolBanc = bol.GerarBoleto(RetornarItemList(item.NumeroDocumento));
                bolBanc = bol.GerarBoletoBradesco(RetornarItemList(item.NumeroDocumento));
                cd = bolBanc.Cedente;
                lb.Add(bolBanc.Boleto);
                break;

            }

            System.IO.FileStream arq = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\Temp\\arqRemessa.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Append);

            cd.Endereco = new BoletoNet.Endereco
            {
                Bairro = "Teste",
                CEP = "02764-020",
                Cidade = "São Paulo",
                End = "Teste end",
                Logradouro = "Rua",
                Numero= "4",
                UF= "SP"
            };

            BoletoNet.ArquivoRemessa arqRem = new BoletoNet.ArquivoRemessa(BoletoNet.TipoArquivo.Outro);

            arqRem.GerarArquivoRemessa("3480291", new BoletoNet.Banco(237), cd, lb,
                arq, 1);


            return View("/home/index");
        }

public ActionResult ImprimirBoleto(string Fatura, string NovaDtVenc = "")
        {
            Boleto bol = new Boleto();
            BoletoNet.BoletoBancario bolBanc = new BoletoNet.BoletoBancario();

            bolBanc = bol.GerarBoletoBradesco(RetornarItemList(Fatura));

            if (NovaDtVenc != "")
            {
                bolBanc.Boleto.DataVencimento = DateTime.Parse(NovaDtVenc);
                bolBanc.Boleto.DataDocumento = DateTime.Now;
            }

            //HTML que monta o boleto.
 // Aqui dá o erro falando que não foi passado o valor pro objeto BoletoNet.Conta
            var htmlBoleto = bolBanc.MontaHtml(Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/Boletos/"), "");
            htmlBoleto = htmlBoleto
            .Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], "\\") // convertendo o caminho absoluto para relativo
            .Replace(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), Url.Action("Temporario", "Faturas") + "/?filename=") // convertendo o caminho temporário em relativo
            .Replace(".w666{width:666px}", ".w666{width:21cm}")
            .Replace("<body>", "<body style=\"height:29cm\">")
            //.Replace("</html>", "<a length=\"0\" href=\"/Faturas/PrintBoleto?Fatura=subsFatura\" >Exportar PDF</a></html>")
            .Replace("</html>", "<a length=\"0\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.print();\">Imprimir/Exportar PDF</a></html>")
            .Replace("subsFatura", Fatura.Replace("/","%2F"))
            //.Replace("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">", "")
            //.Replace("Imprimir em impressora jato de tinta (ink jet) ou laser em qualidade normal. (Não use modo econômico).<br>Utilize folha A4 (210 x 297 mm) ou Carta (216 x 279 mm) - Corte na linha indicada<br>","")
            //.Replace("&nbsp;","")
            ;
            ViewBag.Boleto = htmlBoleto.ToString();

            return View();

        }
```

Comment: Cara, aqui não é melhor lugar para se fazer questões específicas sobre o `boleto.net`. Mas, de qualquer maneira, existe um projeto só com exemplos em https://github.com/BoletoNet
Espero que te ajude

Comment: Coloque seu código, dê mais subsídios para podermos ajudar. Ah, eu sei que não tem nada melhor pronto disponível, mas aquele código é bem mal feito.

Comment: Tô ligado @JéfersonBueno, é que cara eu fui fazer uma coisa simples e complicou rs. Tô com esse erro de um objeto que fala que não está sendo passado mas na verdade eu já passei valor pra esse objeto.

Comment: @AndreeH coloque o código para tentarmos ajudar. Aliás, tu baixou a dll de algum lugar ou está usando o **nuget**?

Comment: @bigown, puts só está dando erro na hora de montar o boleto. Esse código foi outra pessoa que fez, eu só preciso alterar onde hoje passa dados do Santander para Bradesco.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno, esse código já estava feito, eu peguei pra alterar o boleto de santander para bradesco e pelo o que vi, foi baixado da net essa dll.

Comment: Se você não puder nos dar informação para ajudar sua pergunta será considerada não clara e será fechada. Ficar repetindo a mesma coisa não ajuda ninguém, dar informações relevantes ajuda. Não temos como adivinhar qual é seu problema sem ver o que está fazendo.

Comment: @bigown, coloquei o código que passa quando mando imprimir o boleto.

Comment: Que erro acontece? Onde? Dê detalhes.

Comment: @bigown da o erro "A descrição para o banco BoletoNet.Banco não foi implementada.". No metodo "ImprimirBoleto" na hora de montarHtml da esse erro. Mas eu implementei esse objeto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este software é mal feito e incompleto. Se você quiser usar desta forma terá que completá-lo. Veja o que causa o problema:

```
switch (Banco.Codigo) {
    case 1:
        descricaoCarteira = new Carteira_BancoBrasil(carteira).Codigo;
        break;
    case 353:
    case 8:
    case 33:
        descricaoCarteira = new Carteira_Santander(carteira).Codigo;
        break;
    case 104:
        descricaoCarteira = new Carteira_Caixa(carteira).Codigo;
        break;
    case 341:
        descricaoCarteira = new Carteira_Itau(carteira).Codigo;
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception($"A descrição para o banco {Boleto.Banco} não foi implementada."));
        throw new Exception($"A descrição da carteira {carteira} / banco {Banco.Codigo} não foi implementada (marque false na propriedade MostrarCodigoCarteira)"));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Boleto.cs).

Não tem Bradesco. Vai ter que adicionar um `case` aí [neste código](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/blob/cd385299bf12ace234a4719a060d79aed7b12d82/src/Boleto.Net/BoletoImpressao/BoletoBancario.cs). Mas é claro que não basta isto. Isto não deveria ser tratado desta forma, fere vários princípios de programação, mas é o que tem.

Veja que no [repositório dele](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/tree/d70bcaf4bdfbebb86eb01bef346239787099afe9/src/Boleto.Net/Boleto/Carteira) não existe a implementação da carteira que quer usar. Você terá que criar uma para o Bradesco. Acredito que será fácil copiar um arquivo de outro banco e adaptar só o que é necessário. Deveria ser até mais fácil que isto mas o código não ajuda, é mal arquitetado.

Ou seja, só com a DLL, você não vai resolver o problema, vai ter que mexer no código deles. O que é um absurdo. Se fizer isso direito, tente mandar no GitHub e veja se eles aceitam para que outros possam usufruir da sua melhoria.

Mas pode ser que tenha uma outra solução se você puder abrir mão de um recurso. Se mudar uma propriedade, este código que dá erro não executa. Veja no fonte que você deve ter criado para o Bradesco e mude a a propriedade `MostrarCodigoCarteira` para `false`. Veja onde está no [arquivo existente do Santander](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/blob/d70bcaf4bdfbebb86eb01bef346239787099afe9/src/Boleto.Net.Site/Bancos/Santander.aspx.cs).

O uso de exceção desta forma parece inadequado.

Comment: beleza, obrigado.

Comment: em que ponto eu posso adicionar este trecho e adicionar o case do Bradesco ?

Comment: Qualquer lugar aí onde mostrei pra você. Editei para dar mais uma solução parcial.

Comment: O mais legal é que [no Wiki do cara, ele fala que o layout para o Bradesco está implementado](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/wiki/Bancos-Implementados) hehehehe. Se quiserem, eu altero e faço um *pull request* pro autor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez acho que o *layout* está mesmo. Não vi, não está todas as partes. Esta parece ser opcional, por isso a maioria consegue usar. Não tive tempo pra ver tudo. Cheguei pensar em fazer um *fork* e arrumar algumas coisas erradas, mas tem tanto problema só no que eu vi que se um dia for mexer com isto, melhor fazer do zero. Viu os 2 `throw`s seguidos? :)

Comment: Sim. Uma obra de arte.

Comment: @bigown, eu mudei o MostrarCodigoCarteira para false e funcionou.